# Getting an 'incompatible pointer types assigning to...' error with basic string combining method

Tags: objective-c, string, methods

I am working my way through learning Objective-C and just had a quick question. I'm not sure what I'm missing here. I'm getting an 'incompatible pointer types assigning to...' error with the following code (Please note, I'm aware that this code could be more simply written and I could just run the stringByAppendingString method without using a custom class, however this is more for the purpose of learning so that I can pass/return strings to methods in more complex classes.) :

Exact error : Incompatible pointer types assigned to 'SCClass *' from 'NSString *'

**Main.m**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "SCClass.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        NSString *firstString = @"String One... ";
        NSString *secondString = @"String Two";

        SCClass *combinedString = [[SCClass alloc]init];

        combinedString = [combinedString combineFirstString:firstString withSecondString:secondString];
        // Getting error on this line.

        NSLog(@"%@", combinedString);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

**SCClass.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface SCClass : NSObject

-(NSString*) combineFirstString: (NSString*) x withSecondString: (NSString*) y;

@end
```

**SCClass.m**

```
#import "SCClass.h"

@implementation SCClass

-(NSString*) combineFirstString: (NSString*) x withSecondString: (NSString*) y; {

    return [x stringByAppendingString:y];

}

@end
```

Comment: Update your question with the exact and complete error.

Comment: Should be `NSString *newString = [combinedString combineFirstString:firstString withSecondString:secondString];`.

Comment: Ah ok, got it now, thanks rmaddy